# How does choice blindness affect UX research?

Tags: user-research, bias, users-tests

Recently came across this Ted talk about a phenomenon called choice blindness.

from the link:
Experimental psychologist Petter Johansson researches choice blindness -- a phenomenon where we convince ourselves that we're getting what we want, even when we're not. In an eye-opening talk, he shares experiments (designed in collaboration with magicians!) that aim to answer the question: Why do we do what we do? The findings have big implications for the nature of self-knowledge and how we react in the face of manipulation. You may not know yourself as well as you think you do.

https://www.ted.com/talks/petter_johansson_do_you_really_know_why_you_do_what_you_do?utm_campaign=social&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=talk&utm_term=social-science

How does this impact the results of ux research? Does that mean it will be biased?

For instance if we show a user the what looks like a popular and prominent commerce website (e.g. asos) but we replace the experiences with poor ux, would the participants come up with reasoning that the overall experience is good.

What are your thoughts??

Comment: This is too much of a discussion topic than a problem needing a solution. Probably a better fit for Quora or perhaps a blog post in its own right, but StackExchange isn't the place for it.

Comment: @JonW - the initial question closes with, "What are your thoughts?" This may seem like a subjective discussion, but actually, this is asking if UX is an opinion OR is there proof? I supplied an answer that indicates that there is some proof based on real research. Would you consider removing the [on hold] status and allow other members to bring researched answers?

Comment: The brain didn't evolve to handle deliberate (or unintentional) manipulation, because nature does not lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UX measures many things, but usually on the micro-scale. For example, a UX research can prove if a button is placed proficiently. I have not seen UX research that measures holistic experience.

But I do know of a theory called The Aesthetic-Usability Effect in which states that good (or popular) designs are assumed to be good UX. People tend to trust good looks even if the good looks are not good design (i.e. politicians). Read more at Nielsen Norman Group's article on The Aesthetic-Usability Effect.

Is this what you're asking -- do people presume prominent sites MUST be a good experience just because it's a prominent site? The answer is mostly, yes. Users are sheep.

Comment: Hey, it worked for famous art in the mid-20th century.